# Scraping game data from web

Tags: python

My code currently:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from tabulate import tabulate
from datetime import datetime
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

start = datetime.now()

browser = webdriver.Chrome()


class GameData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []


def parse_data(url):
    browser.get(url)
    df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]
    time.sleep(3)
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = bs(html,"lxml")
    cont = soup.find('div', {'id':'wrap'})
    conti = cont.find('div', {'id':'col-content'})
    content = conti.find('table', {'class':'table-main'}, {'id':'tournamentTable'})
    main = content.find('th', {'class':'first2 tl'})
    count = main.findAll('a')
    country = count[1].text
    league = count[2].text
    game_data = GameData()
    game_date = None
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if not isinstance(row[1], str):
            continue
        elif ':' not in row[1]:
            game_date = row[1].split('-')[0]
            continue
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[1])
        game_data.game.append(row[2])
        game_data.score.append(row[3])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[6])
    browser.quit()
    return game_data, country, league

# You can input as many URLs you want
urls = {
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/champions-league/results/"
}

if __name__ == '__main__':

    results = None

    for url in urls:
        game_data, country, competition = parse_data(url)
        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
        result['country'] = country
        result['competition'] = competition
        if results is None:
            results = result
        else:
            results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)


results

|    | date        | time   | game                                 | score   |   home_odds |   draw_odds |   away_odds | country   | competition      |
|----|-------------|--------|--------------------------------------|---------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-----------|------------------|
|  0 | 17 Mar 2021 | 20:00  | Bayern Munich - Lazio                | 2:1     |        1.35 |        6.02 |        7.53 | Europe    | Champions League |
|  1 | 17 Mar 2021 | 20:00  | Chelsea - Atl. Madrid                | 2:0     |        2.33 |        3.1  |        3.49 | Europe    | Champions League |
|  2 | 16 Mar 2021 | 20:00  | Manchester City - B. Monchengladbach | 2:0     |        1.28 |        6.25 |       10.17 | Europe    | Champions League |
|  3 | 16 Mar 2021 | 20:00  | Real Madrid - Atalanta               | 3:1     |        2.26 |        3.6  |        3.16 | Europe    | Champions League |
|  4 | 10 Mar 2021 | 20:00  | Liverpool - RB Leipzig               | 2:0     |        2.37 |        3.8  |        2.85 | Europe    | Champions League |
```

How can I make this code better for readability?

Also, since CR is asking to explain further, (mods can delete this)

Answer (score 1):

Some quick comments. Since your request is about readability, you can do three things at least:

- get rid of unused variables eg: `start = datetime.now()`
- improve the naming conventions for your variables: variables like `cont` or `conti are` quite similar (risk of typos/confusion) but the names are not intuitive and do not accurately describe the data you are manipulating. `count` is also too generic to be meaningful. Note that game_date looks confusingly similar to game_data and you even have a line: `game_data.date.append(game_date)`. I think the risk of typo bugs is not negligible here.
- add some line spacing here and there, plus a few comments. You can afford it as the code is less than 100 lines of code, so the implementation is reasonable and not bloated.

I don't think the class `GameData` is really useful the way it is implemented. To get the final printable result you could stick with a dataframe, you already have one, so see if it can be transformed further or transposed to another.

You have `time.sleep` after `pd.read_html`, but it does not guarantee that the page will be fully loaded. There are several functions in Selenium that you can use to wait for the presence of a given element. But probably you could use the requests module instead. On sites that use JS/Ajax, you may have no other choice but to use Selenium, but it takes more effort to do it right.

It would be good to add some **validation** to make sure that the result of your scraping is not void. Otherwise the processing will be wrong and return garbage. The BS `find` function will return None if the element is not found. So all you have to do is something like:

```
if None in (cont, conti, content, main):
```

or you can use the `any` function for this purpose.
However, `findAll` has a different behavior and will return an empty list if there is no matching element found.

Comment: Thanks. Very useful.

`I don't think the class GameData is really useful the way it is implemented. To get the final printable result you could stick with a dataframe, you already have one, so see if it can be transformed further or transposed to another`

Can you help me with this bit?